# vs_buildtools.exe not running in the container

Tags: visual-studio, docker, build-tools, nano-server

I followed the instructions to install Visual Studio Build Tools from [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2019). Instead of installing it into a Server Core, I installed it into a Windows Nano Server. The build appears to be successful. When I create a container from this image, I can see that vs_buildtools.exe is in the TEMP directory. However, it does not appear any directory called BuildToolsor related - it seems like it wasn't even installed. If I try to run vs_buildtools.exe again, it does not output anything and nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Build Tools can only be installed if the machine has a .NET framework. Since Nanoserver does not support .NET frameworks, then the executable will not run. I installed it in Servercore, even though it is not optimal since it is heavier.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/net-core-net-framework-containers/net-container-os-targets

Comment: Thanks this was bugging me to. Would at least be nice if `vs_buildtools.exe` failed with an error message and appropriate exit code. 

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, `vs_buildtools.exe` is a 32-bit executable, and Nano Server only supports 64-bit executables.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/getting-started-with-nano-server

> It is similar to Windows Server in Server Core mode, but significantly smaller, has no local logon capability, **and only supports 64-bit applications**, tools, and agents.